# UNION ALL two SELECTs with different column types - expected behaviour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, standards, union-all

What is the expected behaviour due to SQL Standard when we perform `UNION` on two tables with different data types:

```
create table "tab1" ("c1" varchar(max));
create table "tab2" ("c3" integer);
insert into tab1 values(N'asd'), (N'qweqwe');
insert into tab2 values(123), (345);
select
c_newname as myname
from
(
select "c1" as c_newname from "tab1"
union all
select "c3" from "tab2"
) as T_UNI;
```

`MS SQL Server` gives

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'asd' to data type
>   int.

but what is defined in the standard?

Comment: not sure where "tab3" came from but you can't union two different datatypes. That's what SQL Server is telling you.

Comment: @ChristianBarron Thanks, tab3 is meant to be tab1, sorry. I understand what SQL Server is telling me, I wonder what the SQL Standard says on this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `union all` columns in every query need to have the same type.`C3` must be converteted to varchar because `c1` is varchar. Try below solution

```
create table "tab1" ("c1" varchar(max));
create table "tab2" ("c3" integer);
insert into tab1 values(N'asd'), (N'qweqwe');
insert into tab2 values(123), (345);
select
c_newname as myname
from
(
select "c1" as c_newname from "tab1"
union all
select cast("c3"  as varchar(max)) from "tab2"
) as T_UNI;
```

I replaced `"tab3"` with `"tab1"` - I think it's typo.

Comment: Thanks for your effort - I am aware of the possibility to fix the query that way, but I am still wondering what the SQL Standard expects.

Comment: @alex As I said above. Columns types in every query should be matched.If 1st column is int every query should return int value.

Answer (score 9):

From [T-SQL UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) page:

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two
>   queries by using UNION:
>
> - The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
> - The data types must be compatible.

When one datatype is `VARCHAR` and other is `INTEGER` then SQL Server will implicitly attempt to convert `VARCHAR` to `INTEGER` (the rules are described in the precedence table). If conversion fails for any row, the query fails. So this works:

```
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(N'123'), (N'345');
INSERT INTO #tab2 VALUES(123), (345);
SELECT C1 FROM #tab1 UNION ALL SELECT C2 FROM #tab2
```

But this does not:

```
INSERT INTO #tab1 VALUES(N'ABC'), (N'345');
INSERT INTO #tab2 VALUES(123), (345);
SELECT C1 FROM #tab1 UNION ALL SELECT C2 FROM #tab2
-- Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ABC' to data type int.
```

The rules for conversion are described here:

[T-SQL Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

---

Having said that, you can *explicitly* convert your integer data to varchar in order to make the query work (the datatype of result would be varchar).

Comment: cool, thanks for the reference to data type precedence, I did not know this.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule is-->
**Either the datatype used should be same in two table**(or)**you should use cast or convert function to match the datatypes in those two tables**.

SQL Standard:

1)The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries.
2)Column datatypes must be compatible: They need not be the same exact same type, but they must be of a type that SQL Server can implicitly convert.