# how to union 2 tables based on specific columns in sas

Tags: sql, types, union, multiple-columns

I want to union 2 tables, but get the error

```
proc sql;
select * from Table1
outer union corr
select * from table2;
```

But get the error:

```
ERROR: The type of column EntryId from the left hand side of the OUTER UNION set operation is
       different from EntryId on the right hand side
```

If I understand this correct and based on [UNION ALL two SELECTs with different column types - expected behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049489/union-all-two-selects-with-different-column-types-expected-behaviour), the first column is a different data type and cannot proceed with the union (which is true)

```
RecordID num label='RecordID' format=20. informat=20.
and
RecordID num label='RecordID' format=11. informat=11.
```

BUT, there is a column I want to use which has the same format

```
Pseu char(64) label='Pseu' format=$64. informat=$64.
Pseu char(64) label='Pseu' format=$64. informat=$64.
```

and in each table they are columns 3 and 4.

Is there a way to union these table together using that column as the reference, as opposed to the original?

I tried to no avail:

```
proc sql;
select * from Table1
outer union corr
select * from table2
on Table1.Pseu=Table2.Pseu;

ERROR: Found "on" when expecting ;
```

It follows from the OUTER UNION CORRESPONDING example given on http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473694.htm, and is here based on what I want:

```
table1              
R   y   p       
1   A   100     
2   B   101     
3   R   102     

table2              
R   z   p       
4   A   102     
5   R   103     
6   T   104     

MERGED              
p   R   y   R   z
100 1   A       
101 2   B       
102 3   R   4   A
103         5   R
104         6   T
```

Comment: Add some sample data for both tables, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: updated request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer supplied by my search and jarlh were correct.

The issues arose due to the size and number of columns in the data sets to be union'd. I had to make sure that there were no column names repeated in the union'd data sets (in my 600 total columns, some had similar names), so I had to rename columns

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
proc sql;
select * from Table1
outer union corr
select p, r as r2, z from table2
```

Having a column alias for the column r.

Using a regular UNION:

```
select p, r, y, null, null from Table1
outer union corr
select p, null, null, r as r2, z from table2
```

Comment: Are you sure your dbms  have OUTER UNION?

Comment: I am new to SQL, how can I determine if that is the case?