# Join two diffrent datatype columns SQL

Tags: sql

Table2:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 09-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | P |

Table3:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 10-12-2022 | Absent | A |

Table4:

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | INAM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 09-12-2022 | 8:30 AM | P |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 10-12-2022 | Absent | A |

```
IF OBJECT_ID('table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table2
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID int, Name varchar(50), Class varchar(20), Date date, Intime time, INAM varchar(20))
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 'Paul', '1st', '09-12-2022', '8:30AM', 'P')

IF OBJECT_ID('table3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table3
CREATE TABLE table3 (ID int, Name varchar(50), Class varchar(20), Date date, Intime varchar(50), INAM varchar(20))
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (1, 'Paul', '1st', '10-12-2022', 'Absent', 'A')
IF OBJECT_ID('table4') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE table4
CREATE TABLE table3 (ID int, Name varchar(50), Class varchar(20), Date date, Intime time, INAM varchar(20))
INSERT INTO table4
SELECT
 table2.ID,table2.Name,table2.Class,table2.Date,table2.Intime,table2.INAM,
 table3.ID,table3.Name,table3.Class,table3.Date,table3.Intime,table3.INAM
FROM table2
JOIN table3 ON  convert(varchar(50),table2.intime) = convert(varchar(50),table3.intime)
select * from table4
```

Could someone help me to join table2, table3 and result in table4. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[UNION ALL two SELECTs with different column types - expected behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049489/union-all-two-selects-with-different-column-types-expected-behaviour)

Check this comment, maybe UNION and converting data types can help.

Comment: Thats a tip not an answer... an answers provides a complete solution to the problem asked. And in fact should have been flagged as a duplicate.